# Android - Why my app's menu button on the toolbar is disappeared?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I didn't delete any default code, but the menu button on the toolbar is disappeared. Neither the tag. The toolbar is just blank like this:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrI9b.png)

Menu xml like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.qiaoliang.bluetoothchat.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Scan" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Name" />
```

Activity menu part code like this

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.name:
            ...
            break;
        case R.id.scan:
            ...
            break;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: did you try running it on a device or even the emulator?

Comment: You should show us how you have your toolbar set up. Are you using a Toolbar enabled theme, or do you have an xml file for your Toolbar and are adding that to each layout? If the latter, you need to add "setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_name))" in your onCreate method.